# Adding support for extensions in phone number input with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript

I have a function that works well to mask phone number (type="tel") inputs as a user types.

However I'd like to add support so the user can throw an extension on the number if needed like so (123) 456-7890 x12345

I'm not clear on how to edit my regex to support this.

```
(function() {

  // finds all phone number inputs 
  var phoneNumberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type=tel]');

  // a function that formats the number while typing
  function maskPhoneInputs() {
    this.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
      e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
    });
  }

  // to apply the function to each input
  phoneNumberInputs.forEach(maskPhoneInputs);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here it is:

```
  function maskPhoneInputExt() {
      this.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
          var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})?(\d{0,8})/);
          e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '') + (x[4] ? ' x' + x[4] : '');
      });
    }
```

Needed to add the optional subexpression `?(\d{0,8})` at the end of the match method.

Also added  `+ (x[4] ? ' x' + x[4] : '')` to the value assignment.